# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop Menu Bar and upper panel missing, windows cannot be dragged, closed etc

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, menu, gdm

I spent the entire day yesterday til 3am trying to fix this, and all the possible solutions you can find on the web just don't work for me.

I agreed to some regular updates on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, all worked fine. Ever since starting back up, only the stuff that was lying around on my Desktop is to be seen.
One of the "fixes" even caused a blackscreen and I couldn't even boot my OS anymore, I had to start a Ubuntu safe session and reconfigure lightdm in the terminal to even make my OS work again. I'm also still confused on why it allows you to choose between lightdm and gdm as a manager.

I checked the `.xsession-errors` file and it reports

```
...
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (4644) terminated with status 1
...
```

metacity --replace & disown at least temporarily allows me to minimise, drag and close windows.

ccsm won't apply any changes made at all after I close it.

I've tried everything google can find for you...

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
setsid unity
unity --reset-icons
reinstall unity
reinstall ubuntu desktop
initctl restart unity-panel-service
update, upgrade, dist-upgrade
aptitude
etc....
```

Absolutely NOTHING works!!

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you sign into a guest session OK? Do you know the date updates were applied?

Comment: upstart? in 16.04.4? To the best of my knowledge upstart was replaced with systemd around 15.04. VTC as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Check the unity package details:

```
dpkg -l | grep unity
```

If 'unity' is listed in the output, proceed with the next step. If not, install it (and its dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
```

As you mention you installed ubuntu desktop, then also I suggest perform this:
Check the ubuntu desktop package details:

```
dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-desktop
```

If 'ubuntu-desktop' is not listed, install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Restart your system once, if problem not solved then reply with the outputs.

Comment: It looks like the OP already tried this.